# Offline Repository or CD Source

Tags: repository, offline

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on a physical machine which cannot be connected to the internet. The originally ISO was downloaded from Ubuntu's official site and burnt straight to CD.

From various googling, I've discovered a way to add a CD to the local repository (Software Centre, Edit, Software Sources...) but it can't pick up any of the packages. Equally, I've tried to find packages on the CD and I'm convinced they aren't there. I've also attempted multiple other routes but none of them work (I'm unsure if it's because of the version or not).

How do I **FIND** packages **OFFLINE** ( I don't mind downloading the repository if it makes it easier) and be able to install a package with all of it's dependencies? Heck, if I can't do the latter I don't mind doing it one by one.

Comment: Does this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline/1002#1002 help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a local offline repository

And then add it to the top of /etc/apt/sources.list

Click [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1090731)!
This link will help to create signed Local Repository, which will enable you to install packages Offline.